# Next/Image: Dragging image doesn't work when src comes from another website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, drag-and-drop, nextjs-image

I can drag the following image:

```
const src = "/logo/title.png"; 

...

<Image
  loader={({ src }) => src}
  src="/logo/title.png"
  alt="logo"
  width={65}
  height={65}
  layout="fixed"
  draggable
/>
```

But when src is from another website, the image can't be dragged:

```
const src = "http://localhost:8000/media/gelano_3.png"; 

...

<Image
  loader={({ src }) => src}
  src="/logo/title.png"
  alt="logo"
  width={65}
  height={65}
  layout="fixed"
  draggable
/>
```

Why and how can i fix it ?

Comment: The image is correctly uploaded but I can't drag it. I cannot download the image because it comes from a request, for the example I wrote it hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

it is the attribute `loader={({ src }) => src}` which prevents the image from being dragged